# With Java DatagramSockets, can I connect two different sockets to the same local port but on different local addresses?

Tags: java, sockets, udp

With Java DatagramSockets, can I connect two different sockets to the same local port but on two different local addresses?

I have this situation. My computer has a WiFi card and an ethernet cable connected. The Wifi and the Ethernet are both working and they have two different addresses ("192.168.10.104" and "192.168.10.108") . When I create a pair of DatagramSocket, I do:

```
final String wiFiCardAddressName = "192.168.10.104";
final String ethernetAddressName = "192.168.10.108";
final InetAddress wiFiCardAddress = InetAddress.getByName(wiFiCardAddressName);
final InetAddress ethernetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ethernetAddressName)
DatagramSocket datagramSocket1 = DatagramSocket(8000, wiFiCardAddress);
DatagramSocket datagramSocket2 = DatagramSocket(8000, ethernetAddress);
// ...
```

Will this work? Would all the packets for one socket go through WiFi and all the packets for the other socket go through Ethernet? Why or why not?

Comment: Yes, you can. And yes, it does work. It works because that is how routing works. (If you are expecting it to work like it does work.) This is a function of IP - under either TCP or UDP - in general.

Comment: So if I disconnect the ethernet, then one of the two datagramSockets will stop working and the other one will keep working?

Comment: Yes, if you disconnect the interface it'll be .. disconnected. It's a bit more complex if strictly talking about routing (ie. it would still be possible to make a connection via the other interface) but this question asks about *binding* and binding is per-interface (even '*' can be thought of as per-every/any-interface).

Comment: What if I bind to the wildcard address. DatagramSocket(8000, "0.0.0.0"); Does that mean that my DatagramSocket will get the packet regardless of whether it comes from the Ethernet or the WiFi address?

Comment: If I bind to (8000, "0.0.0.0") and then disconnect the ethernet, get a packet on port 8000, reconnect the ethernet, disconnect the WiFi, get another packet on port 8000, would I would successfully get both packets, the one where the ethernet was disconnected and also the one where the WiFi was disconnected?

Comment: The port is *always* per IP (on each respective IP/interface bound). However, I'm not sure how the system would behave in that case - never tried it, and it might be OS / IP-stack specific. Would be a fun little experiment, I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as long as neither of the addresses is 0.0.0.0.

> If I bind to (8000, "0.0.0.0") and then disconnect the ethernet, get a packet on port 8000, reconnect the ethernet, disconnect the WiFi, get another packet on port 8000, would I would successfully get both packets, the one where the ethernet was disconnected and also the one where the WiFi was disconnected?

The question isn't clear. If you mean that a wifi packet arrives while wifi is connected and the Ethernet is disconnected, and then an Ethernet packet arrives while the Ethernet is connected and the wifi is disconnected, then yes, you should get whatever arrives via a connected interface. 0.0.0.0 is sometimes referred to as 'all', but it really means 'any'.